# Using getJSONArray without string name

Tags: android, json

I am trying to parse a JSON file in the following structure

```
{
"category": {
    "subcat_1": [
        {
            "item1": "xx"
        },
        {
            "item2": "xx"
        }
    ],
    "subcat_2": [
        {
            "item1": "xx"
        },
        {
            "item2": "xx"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

It is working when am using getJSONArray("subcat_1") but, i want to get these string without the need to pre-save them in an array { subcat_1, subcat_2, ... } to maintain the dynamic feature?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the keys for the object using `keys()`, which returns an Iterator:

```
Iterator it = json.keys();
while(it.hasNext()) {
  String key = (String)it.next();
  JSONObject current = json.getJSONObject(key);
  // do something with current
}
```